# Why can't I change href programmatically when Angular Service worker is used?

Tags: angular-service-worker

I'm trying to change a link's href programmatically in an external webpage that uses an Angular Service worker.

The link looks like `<a _ngcontent-c32="" href="/something">Something</a>` and uses this EventListener:

```
function(e){if(e=e||t.event){var n=this||e.target||t,r=n[C[e.type][f]];if(r)if(1===r.length)y(r[0],n,e);else for(var i=r.slice(),o=0;o<i.length&&(!e||!0!==e[z]);o++)y(i[o],n,e)}}
```

When I run
`document.querySelector('a').setAttribute('href', '/something-else')` or `document.querySelector('a').href = '/something-else'` I can see the href did technically get changed, but the webpage completely ignores it when I click the link and uses the original href instead.

Is there something I can do to make the Service Worker be aware of this change?

Comment: Why don't you use a variable instead with a default value of "/something" assigned to it and change that variable programatically and use it in html like so

<a _ngcontent-c32="" [href]="link">Something</a>

Comment: Just clarified that's it's an external webpage. What do I do in that case?

Answer (score 1):

first try to use angular property `[attr.href]` or `[href]` and by using this you can change url programmatically by using ternary condition.

```
<a [href]="reverse ? 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53492185/why-cant-i-change-href-programmatically-in-angular' : 'https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview'" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

> Note: these both properties will not append `base URL` so you need to
>   specify complete path.

Comment: But it's an external webpage, what do I do in that case?